# All songs are starting simultaneously instead of one after another

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

```
WindowsMediaPlayer[] player = new WindowsMediaPlayer[31];

for(int i = 1; i < 30 ; i++ )
{
    player[i] = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
    player[i].URL = @"C://Songs//m" + i + ".mp3";
    player[i].controls.play();
}
```

here I am using array to store the url and to play. but all the songs are starting at one time instead of one after another.How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a bad title and bad formatting. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title and [FAQ]

Comment: You are creating Windows 31 Media Player Object Model Reference :O Are sure what you are doing here?

Comment: Put some delay in that loop?

Comment: may be the dll connection was not proper. once check and do..
if not , remove the dll set completely and add it again properly.

Comment: Your Array contains not 31 Media Players, it only has 31 Reference to the same WMP ActivX Control. PLEASE Read the SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564680(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you create multiple instances of the control and let them all play one song. You should just create one instance add all songs to the "CurrentPlaylist" and then let the control play it:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer;

        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
        {
            IWMPMedia media = player.newMedia( @"C://Songs//m" + i + ".mp3");
            player.currentPlaylist.appendItem(media);                
        }

        player.controls.play();
```

Comment: how to generate random number in between. So, that the player should play random songs.Is it possible?. If possible then please provide me the code...